# positioning xticks arbitrarily in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Python, I have two list that have 10 elements each. I plot these against each other in pyplot.

I know that I am able to use **xticks** to position the ticks, but it seems that I am limited to putting the ticks at one of the 10 points on my x axis.

Is it possible to put my tick locations at any arbitrary location that I chose along the x axis? Perhaps by choosing the fraction of the axis length or something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `pyplot.xticks([1, 3, 10, 20])`, or whatever arbitrary numbers you like.